# Google Colab frozen after trying to unzip huge file

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've tried to unzip a huge image dataset from CelebA (http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html) in my Google Colab notebook. The unified 7z file was about 10gb.

When I tried to unzip it, the progress was so slow that I wanted to cancel it. 
I tried:

- Restarting Runtime
- Changing Runtime Type (GPU, NO-GPU)
- Creating an entirely new Notebook

None of this works. All my notebooks are frozen as soon as I try to execute something. The only thing I have not tried is to log in with another user, but that would defeat the purpose of this question.

Does someone know what to do other than wait and hope? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anyway, I added an Issue here https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/235

Answer (score 4):

Try using the -q (quiet) argument along with unzip command to not display every file being unzipped, this will definitely speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue. I ran a cell that was printing like crazy, and I got my browser frozen. Each time I tried to reopen the Colab file, it got frozen again.

To solve this, I:

1. Went on Drive to the Colab folder
2. Duplicated the Colab file (right-click > duplicate)
3. Deleted the previous one
4. Open the duplicated one.

Then no runtime was associated with it, so I could change the code in my cell.